# Restore quicklaunch back to default

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, quick-launch

Is there a way to restore the Quick launch to it's default settings?  Customer deleted headings and items and want to restore them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can't restore the quick launch after deletion, moreover this is a navigation link not the actual list or site.. still those sites or lists will be available. So, you can reconfigure the quick launch again... if it was very complicated navigation, you even code it. And also, check in your test environment whether you had similar quick launch navigation, you may refer that.

Finally, if you maintain a daily site backup, you can restore the site from the latest last backup but in this there will be a big chances of data losses, if you are ready with that, then only go with this.